# Html5 time tag's datetime attribute - day month order

Tags: date, html

What is the correct format for a [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) `<time datetime="" />` attribute?  Do days come before month or vice versa:

```
 <time datetime="yyyy-dd-mm"></time>
```

or

```
 <time datetime="yyyy-mm-dd"></time>
```

where

```
 mm = Month (ie 01)
 dd = Day (ie 20)
```

Comment: I feel like this should be closed... it seems like there's any number of reference websites you could just look this up on. But I don't know if that's a valid reason to close a question or not.

Comment: I found a reason to flag it - this question is basically looking for a link to a manual which makes it off-topic.

Comment: I think it adds value.  It provides an easily digestible and authoritative answer for proper use of a new(-ish) technology.

Comment: It could add value, but it's also attracting low quality and link-only answers, which are then getting flagged and clogging the review queues. So we would close it to prevent anyone else from adding extra answers (it already has as good an answer as one could expect for such a simple question), not delete it entirely.

Comment: Note that the `time` element is not a void element, so the syntax `<time datetime="yyyy-dd-mm" />`, though formally valid, should not be used. When the document is processed as XML (XHTML), it means an element with empty content, which is hardly meaningful, as the content is expected to be a designation of time. In HTML syntax, it is treated just as a start tag, and if there is no matching end tag, certain error recovery is applied, causing some part of the document to be taken as the element’s content.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Good point.  Updating the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `yyyy-mm-dd`, in order to comply with ISO-8601 and general sanity.

From the [W3C proposed recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dates-and-times):

> Note: While the formats described here are intended to be subsets of the corresponding ISO8601 formats, this specification defines parsing rules in much more detail than ISO8601. Implementors are therefore encouraged to carefully examine any date parsing libraries before using them to implement the parsing rules described below; ISO8601 libraries might not parse dates and times in exactly the same manner. [ISO8601]

That's the simplest indication I could find in the recommendation, although there's also the ["dates" section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#dates) which indicates that a date is a [valid-month-string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-month-string) followed by a `-` and then a day, and valid-month-string is defined as:

> A string is a valid month string representing a year year and month month if it consists of the following components in the given order:
>
> - Four or more ASCII digits, representing year, where year > 0
> - A "-" (U+002D) character
> - Two ASCII digits, representing the month month, in the range 1 ≤ month ≤ 12

Comment: It’s not yet a recommendation, but close (Proposed Recommendation).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: Thanks for answering!  While your answer is absolutely correct, I'm awarding it to Jon Skeet because he got the W3C citation.

Answer (score -2):

the second one is correct :
`<time datetime="yyyy-mm-dd" />`

Comment: This should be a comment (or an up vote) instead of a new answer